# Android Studio, login_activity errors

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I am trying to make my first app, since I never did such before I watched a tutorial on how to make a login and register activity with Firebase. After I watched the whole tutorial and typed the code that he was using in the video I got 2 errors. But I can't find a solution. Maybe one of you can help? I got the 2 errors in my login activity. (The code is Java)

```
1        tvRegister.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
2            @Override
3            public void onClick(View v) {
4                Intent intRegister = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
5                startActivity(intRegister);
6            }
7            @Override
8            protected void onStart() {
9                super.onStart();
10                mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
11            }
12 
13        });
14    }
15}
16 
17//-- End of Code --
```

Line 7, "@Override" gives a error: Method does not override method from its superclass

Line 9, "super" gives a error: Calling super.onCreate more than once can lead to crashes

Line 9, "onStart" gives a error: Cannot resolve method 'onStart' in 'Object'

I hope someone can help me out!

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onStart()` method from `ClickListener` and write down to outside of that

```
{
        tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View V) {
                        Intent intRegister = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intRegister);
                    }
                });
}

  @Override
  protected void onStart()
    {
      super.onStart();
      mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
```

Comment: The @Override above the protected void start still gives a error:
"Annotations are not allowed here"

And the first onStart (after protedted void) gives also a error:
"; expected" --> But when I place a ; after, before or in it it still gives the same error.